# Do I actually need to export SyncAdapter service?

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

```
onPerformSync(...) {
    // building status bar notification here
}

<service android:name=".SyncService" android:exported="false"> ...
```

This works for me (4.4.2 SGN3). Notifications appear. Both `requestSync()` and `addPeriodicSync()`.

Do anybody has some thoughts about?

Is there need for exporting `SyncAdapter` service?

What am I actually wanna know is whether any other (enemy) application can start my `exported` service or not. If they can, I don't need to export the service hoping Android isn't so liberal.

I haven't find any clarifications in the Android dev guide/api. I'm pretty novice and I hope my question is correct and understandable enough :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you need to export SyncService for using it from other applications. This is what documentation says:

> The attribute android:exported="true" allows processes other than your app (including the system) to access the Service.

If you don't need to share your sync service to other apps, probably you can leave it not exported. But you need to test it on old versions of android, it's logic might has changed.

Comment: lobzik, do you have any use cases in mind for exporting sync services?

Comment: I think the main reason the service needs to be exposed (exported) is because the service needs to be visible to the android framework so that it will call it when it wants to peform sync.

Comment: @DegenSharew it looks logical, but it also works fine with exported=false.

Comment: really, I did not know that

Comment: If I export the service, will other apps be able to start it? I think, there must be a way to let the system only to start such services.